# Webgoat - changing default path causing app not started properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, webgoat

I am using https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat, trying to change the default path from `/WebGoat` to just `/`. I changed in the application properties file `server.servlet.context-path=/` and rebuild the application.

However after that, I noticed the execution stops at `StartWebGoat.java` stage https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat/blob/main/src/main/java/org/owasp/webgoat/server/StartWebGoat.java when it runs `SpringApplicationBuilder` .

```
    64ca, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2e3b7b0b]
2023-04-13 17:02:30.790  INFO 69552 --- [           main] io.undertow                              : starting server: Undertow - 2.2.18.Final
2023-04-13 17:02:30.794  INFO 69552 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.e.undertow.UndertowWebServer     : Undertow started on port(s) 9090 (http)
```

it didn't proceed with the next step running the `StartUpMessage.Java` https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat/blob/main/src/main/java/org/owasp/webgoat/server/StartupMessage.java

I couldn't find any clue that points to why the event isn't triggered after changing the `context-path` in the `application.properties` file https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat/blob/main/src/main/resources/application-webgoat.properties. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I get to make it work, so from the https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat downloaded,

change the default path in the `src/main/resources/application-webgoat.properties` file, for the line `server.servlet.context-path=/` (from `/WebGoat`)